# How I can count multiplications in an experssion?

Tags: string-manipulation, expression-manipulation, core-language

Next task to complete:

- Count `*`-symbol in such expression as `a + s^2*b - c/y + o^3 + n*m*u` (in this case count of `*` should be 6)
- Powers such $o^3$ should be expand to $o*o*o$

I try, but my code is pretty ugly.

[image]

Comment: Please do not post code in a image. We need code posted as properly formatted text. Please edit your question by replacing the image with properly formatted code. Use the {?) that appears at the top right of the editor panel to learn how to format.

Comment: It may be inappropriate to count $k-1$ multiplications for $x^k$; binary exponentiation can certainly do that with less multiplications in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't give the result you are looking for exactly because it uses the full form of the expression you give it.

```
SetAttributes[countTimes, HoldAll];
countTimes[expr_] := Block[{Times, Power, power, times},
  power[a_, b_ /; b > 0] := Nest[times[a, #] &, a, b - 1];
  power[a_, b_ /; b < 0] := 1/power[a, -b];
  power[a_, 0] := 1;
  times[a___, b_times] := times[Sequence @@ b, a];
  Total[(Length /@ 
        Extract[#, Position[#, times[___]]] &[(expr /. 
         Power -> power) /. Times -> times]) - 1]
  ]

expr = a + s^2*b - c/y + o^3 + n*m*u

countTimes[expr]

(*8*)
```

The reason this gives 8 instead of 6 is because of the term `-c/y` which in full form is `Times[-1,c,Power[y,-1]]`. If you want to treat this specially you will need to add definitions to account for such patterns.

Comment: This does not work. Take a look at `countTimes[a*b*c]`.

Comment: @m_goldberg given the edit I believe this works now though I disagree with the accept.

Answer (score 3):

Accepting that in *Mathematica* `-c/y` is automatically converted to `-1*c*y^-1` and permitting the result shown in Andy's answer I believe we can use a simpler approach, at least for the kind of expression given in example.

Define `rules` that determine how a `Times` or `Power` expression should be counted, then use [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) to find all instances in you expression and total them with [`Tr`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tr.html):

```
rules = {
   _*x__ :> Length@{x},
   _^n_?Positive :> n - 1
 };

expr = a + s^2*b - c/y + o^3 + n*m*u;

Tr @ Cases[expr, #, -2] & /@ rules

Tr @ %
```

> ```
> {5, 3}
>
> 8
> ```

As a single function:

```
fn[expr_] :=
 Tr @ Cases[expr, #, -2] & /@ {_*x__ :> Length@{x}, _^n_?Positive :> n - 1} // Tr
```

---

#### String conversion

If you prefer a string processing result, now accepting that the form *Mathematica* uses may seem rather arbitrary, I propose:

```
stringfn[expr_] := 
  StringCases[
    ToString[expr, InputForm],
    {"*" :> 1, "^" ~~ d__?DigitQ :> FromDigits[d] - 1}
  ] // Tr

a + s^2*b - c/y + o^3 + n*m*u // stringfn
```

> ```
> 6
> ```

Comment: Very much cleaner than mine +1

Comment: @Andy Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is easier to do by working with strings.

First write a function that will expand strings of the form "Power(x,k)" where k is an integer in "x*x*...*x" with k - 1 "*"s.

```
f[x_, k_] :=
  Module[{i = Abs[ToExpression[k]] - 1},
    Nest[StringJoin[#, "*" <> x] &, x, i]]
```

A couple of tests for `f`.

```
f["s", 2]
```

> ```
> "s*s"
> ```

```
f["ab", "-3"]
```

> ```
> "ab*ab*ab"
> ```

Next write a function that will use `f` to transform powers and will count the stars in the expression after `f` has done its transformation.

```
starCount[expr_] :=
  StringCount[
    StringReplace[
      expr // CForm // ToString, 
      "Power(" ~~ v : WordCharacter .. ~~ "," ~~ k : NumberString ~~ ")" :> f[v, k]],
    "*"]

starCount[a + s^2*b - c/y + o^3 + n*m*u]
```

> ```
> 6
> ```

```
starCount[1/(b s^3) + 1/t^4]
```

> ```
> 6
> ```

Note: I use `CForm` to recover the `/`s that represent division, which the OP apparently wants to preserve as a distinct operator.

Comment: I like the idea of string conversion however this seems baroque.  I added what seems like a cleaner alternative to my answer.  Does mine fail where yours does not?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Well, your string munger gets 3 from `1/(b s^3) + 1/t^4` and mine gets 6. Which do you think would be the value the OP would expect?

Comment: Frankly I don't know.  +1 for your interpretation.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Perhaps we can agree that this is a rather difficult question to deal with -- especially since there are not any asterisks at all in a _Mathematica_ numerical expression as the kernel sees them. Are we not counting virtual stars in a symbolic sky with no star to guide us, but only a rather poor example to serve in its place. No wonder there is no agreement on the answer. And, please, don't take this guff I'm spouting seriously.